# Can I keep putting output data on the serial port once I've called tcflow(fildes, TCOOFF)?

Tags: linux, serial-port, communication, rs485

Can I keep putting output data on the serial port once I've called `tcflow(fildes, TCOOFF)`?

I'm trying to fool the port into writing 9-bit data for RS485, when I go from mark parity to space parity, I observe the serial port idle between the sets of characters. I was hoping the UART would store the character and parity in the bit bucket, then I could release it as one, non-broken stream with a `tcflow(fildes, TCOON)`.

Comment: I tried it in a program - a misleading answer to my question is, yes. The truth is, the call to `tcflow(fildes, TCOOFF)` doesn't do anything. I don't know if it's simply not implemented for this particular serial driver or implemented, at all, anywhere.

Comment: *"I observe the serial port break between the sets of characters"* -- Beware of using ordinary words that are also jargon that have a specific/different connotation/meaning.  A [break condition](http://ltxfaq.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/736/~/what-is-a-serial-break%3F) is different from the line being idle (i.e. nothing being sent).  An idle line should not be significant, since it is an asynchronous medium.

Comment: Your userspace application program is at least one layer fully disconnected from control of the UART hardware.  See [Linux serial drivers](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html).  Even if the UART device driver had full responsibility for the parity switching, transmission would have to be paused.  Manipulating parity settings from userspace is going to require a larger idle time.